# Determinant of block matrix with certain properties

Tags: matrices, determinant, block-matrices

I have the following $2n \times 2n$  block matrix

$$H = \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix}$$

where each block is an $n \times n$ matrix and

- $A$ is a strictly upper triangular matrix and $\det(A)=0$.
- $B$ is an upper triangular matrix and $\det(B) \neq 0$
- $C$ is an unitriangular upper matrix and $\det(C) = 1$
- $D$ is an lower triangular matrix and and $\det(D) \neq 0$

I should also mention that the matrices $B$ and $D$ don't permute.

I know that using the Schur complement it is possible to write

$$\det(H) = \det \begin{bmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{bmatrix} = \det(D) \det\left(A-BD^{-1}C\right)$$

I would like to know if, given these conditions, it is possible to prove that $\det(H)\neq 0$. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that you can prove it without assuming something more! If some pair of submatrices commute, you can prove using  http://www.hostemostel.com/pdf/MTH/0.pdf   If you replace $D$ being lower tri with $D$ upper tri, you can prove using row reductions.  But with your conditions you can make an counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an counterexample: All submatrices are $2\times 2$.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
         0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
         0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
         1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
         0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
If you replace your requirement with $D$ being upper triangular (not lower) I think you can prove your claim by row reduction.